# updateing one field in a table at a time in flutter

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

i have made a user table in firebase firestore with multiple fields. and I am saving the data Onchange in text field when the user does any change. But when I change one field it changes all the field in the table and the other data gets altered. but I want to update single field when user updates it.

below is the code that i wrote to update in database -:

```
 FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
 void userinfo() async{
   firestore.collection("users").doc('122345').update(
            {
              "name" : '${username.text}',
              "Describe" : '${describe.text}',
              "SchoolName" : '${school.text}',
              "dob" : '${dob.text}',
              "address" : '${address.text}',
            },
          ). then((_){
            print("success!");
          });
  }
```

```
TextFormField(
                              controller: username,
                              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                              focusNode: fnOne,
                              autofocus: false,
                              maxLines: 1,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                enabled: true,
                                suffixIcon: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 15),
                                  
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.edit,
                                    color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                labelText: Uname,
                              ),
                              onChanged: (value) async{
                                value = username.text;
                                userinfo();
                              },
                              onSaved: (value){
                                value = username.text;
                              },
                            ),
```

I am new to firebase can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update only a subset of the document fields, the Map you pass to the [`update()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/update.html) method needs to contain only the corresponding elements.

For example, the following will update the `SchoolName` field and let the other fields unchanged:

```
 FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
 void userinfo() async{
   firestore.collection("users").doc('122345').update(
            {
              "SchoolName" : '${school.text}',
            },
          ). then((_){
            print("success!");
          });
  }
```

It's up to you to define the Map according to the fields that are modified in the front-end.

---

**Update following your comment:**

You can do as follows to update only the desired field:

```
 FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
 void userinfo(fieldToUpdate, value) async{

   var updateMap = new Map();
   updateMap[fieldToUpdate] = value;

   await firestore.collection("users").doc('122345').update(updateMap);
   print("success!");
  }
```

---

```
TextFormField(
   controller: username,
   // ...
   onChanged: (value) async{
                 value = username.text;
                 userinfo('username', value);
              }
```

Comment: my UI is like a form with multiple text fields as shown above without any submit button which updates when user edits. so ho do I use map here.

Comment: Through each `TextEditingController` you should know which field has been changed => Build the Map with this field only.

Comment: can you show me with an example please as I am getting a bit confused.

Comment: I see now that you use an `onChanged()` callback as follows: `onChanged: (value) async{value = username.text; userinfo();},`. You can pass the field name to the `userinfo()` method, e.g. `userinfo('username');` and in the `userinfo()` method you just pass `username` to the `update()` method.

Comment: then i have to send value for all the textfield and if i define the local variable in the method it will show error in the call back for other values.